# Issue While Setting Spinning Kubernetes using conjure-up

Tags: python, kubernetes, vagrant

Unable to to complete Conjure-up setup to spin up Kubernetes cluster in AWS, here are details of error:

[image]

My conjure version is 2.6.0

Output of `journalctl | grep conjure-up`:

```
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions
```

Output of `$ cat $HOME/.cache/conjure-up/conjure-up.log`:

```
2018-08-22 22:12:03,502 [ERROR] conjure-up/kubernetes-core - provider.py:379 - LXD Parse error: stderr:

error: unknown command: query

2018-08-22 22:12:05,504 [DEBUG] conjure-up/kubernetes-core - provider.py:355 - LXD environment set: binary /usr/bin/lxc lxd_dir /var/lib/lxd

2018-08-22 22:12:05,526 [DEBUG] conjure-up/kubernetes-core - provider.py:372 - LXD query cmd: /usr/bin/lxc query --wait /1.0

2018-08-22 22:12:05,548 [ERROR] conjure-up/kubernetes-core - provider.py:378 - LXD Parse error: stdout: Usage: lxc <command> [options]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still have this problem, take a look [here](https://docs.conjure-up.io/stable/en/user-manual#users-of-lxd)

You basically have to deinstall your current lxd and install it via snap.

1. `sudo apt purge lxc lxd lxd-client`
2. `sudo snap install lxd`
3. `/snap/bin/lxd init`
4. `/snap/bin/lxd.migrate`
5. `sudo usermod -a -G lxd $USER`
6. `newgrp lxd`
7. do a relogin

**UPDATE:**

If that happens i believe it might help to delete that .cache folder:
`rm -rf ~/.cache/conjure-up`

I had a different error - it complained about not being able to get the ip address of the bridge interface - but more me the above helped.

In addition I later on had to issue the following command to "disable" ipv6 nat on the bridge interface, despite answering "none" to the question in `lxd init`:
`lxc network set lxdbr0 ipv6.nat false`